# Where to set permissions to all server for logon trigger on sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to keep track of the last login time for each user in our SQL Server 2005 database.

I created a trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER LogonTimeStamp
ON ALL SERVER FOR LOGON
AS
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM miscdb..user_last_login WHERE user_id = SYSTEM_USER)
    UPDATE miscdb..user_last_login SET last_login = GETDATE() WHERE user_id = SYSTEM_USER
  ELSE
    INSERT INTO miscdb..user_last_login (user_id,last_login) VALUES (SYSTEM_USER,GETDATE())
END;
go
```

This trigger works for users that are system admins but it won't allow regular users to login.  I have granted public select,insert and update to the table but that doesn't seem to be the issue.  Is there a way to set permissions on the trigger?  Is there something else I am missing?

Regular users get the error message:

```
Logon failed for login 'xxxx' due to trigger execution. 
Changed database context to 'xxxx', 
Changed language setting to us_english. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 17892).
```

Thanks

EDIT: We have just noticed that this only happens for active directory accounts, not sql accounts.

For example:

```
C:\>osql -S server -E
Logon failed for login 'xxx\xxxx' due to trigger execution.

C:\>osql -S server -U xxxx
Password:
1>
```

Comment: The problem is that every user with a login to the database isn't a user in the miscdb database.  If they aren't a user in miscdb, they can't login.  We don't want to have to remember to add users to this database when we add them to the database they need.  Is there a way to grant rights to all logins of the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would strongly recommend that you move this table to either [master] or [msdb].  Having a Logon trigger dependent on any non-system database is very problematic.

Secondly, if the current question is "How to grant rights to all logins?" as stated in your comment, then the answer is: "Grant them to the Public server role."  Every login is in that role, so its permissions apply to everyone.

Comment: I didn't want to put the table in master, but it seems that is the only way.  Thanks.  It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TRIGGER [Logon_Audit_Tgr] ON ALL SERVER
    WITH EXECUTE AS 'sa'
    FOR LOGON
AS
    BEGIN ....